# JavaScript request relative page, treat current page as directory

Tags: javascript, jquery

On the page `/document/1` the request `$.getJSON('./json', ...` requests `/document/json`

I would like to request `/document/1/json`

Is there a way I can resolve a path to this without needing to manually read and append to the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `./` is relative to the current directory, and in the path `/document/1`, the directory is `/document`, which contains a "file" named `1`.

You can solve this by adding a trailing slash to the URL (`/document/1/`). In that case, the address is interpreted as the index of the `/document/1` directory.

Or you can use the Location API:

```js
$.getJSON(window.location.pathname + '/json', /* ... */);
```

You can also add the trailing slash with JS:

```js
if (!window.location.pathname.endsWith("/")) {
    const url = new URL(location);
    url.pathname += "/";
    window.history.replaceState(null, "", url);
}
```

Comment: how can I ensure there will be a trailing slash on the url always?

Comment: @minseong Having always a trailing slash may not be a good idea. It depends on what server you're using. Some servers automatically remove trailing slashes if the URL points to a file and automatically add them if it points to a directory.

Comment: Just flask with routing, programmatically rendering and returning data